# PaypalSandbox error

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am working on php . I submit my transaction to paypalsandbox
but transaction is not completed and gives error

An error occurred while processing your request. Before submitting this again, log in and check your Account History to ensure that the transaction didn't complete.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having this in testing too. It was working about 9 hours ago, and as I'm testing from 3 different servers with two different configs, it may be that it's a PayPal issue rather than a user error.

Later:

Found this which suggest it happens from time to time. I'm seeing this error now, rather than the one reported previously.

https://www.x.com/content/resolved-intermittent-errors-during-checkout-sep-21